# Why would a Stream reader fail to actually read a line, but not throw an exception, just passes and empty string?

Tags: c#, arrays, file, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't pin down this exception.  Every time I run this code, it throws an error for out of index when it reaches the char array, it happens half way through, but it does process the first half fine, running the first 100 iterations without a problem, it doesn't just quit when it hits that line the first time. I hardcoded that line and it did another 100 (134 - 194) before the same error again. That makes me wonder if it is a memory problem, even though it is redeclared to a single string on each iteration? i looked into the text file, and the lines it stops at are not different from the rest of the file.... even though it processed another couple lines of it after i looked at the line it was stopping at..... this is confusing., Does anyone know what this problem is?

```c#
     public void edit()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path))
        {

            lines = new String[length()];
            using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Path))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
                {

                        Console.WriteLine("working " + i);
                        lines[i] = read.ReadLine();
/* this is where i fixed it once by hardcosing the data*/       lines[134] = "Brake, Jacob, 10";
                        String line = lines[i];
                        Console.WriteLine("" + line);
             /*the error is on this line half the time */ Console.WriteLine("  " + line[0]);
                        line = CheckLine(line);
                     /*this line the rest*/   char[] c = line.ToCharArray();
                        if (IsEnglishLetter(c[0]))
                        {
                            lines[i] = line;
                            line = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lines[i - 1] = lines[i - 1] + line;
                            lines[i] = null;
                            line = null;
                            changes++;
                        }

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("  " + changes);

            ReWrite();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failure");
        }
    }
```

this is the checkline method:

```
 private string CheckLine (String line)
    {
        if(line.StartsWith(" "))
        {
            line = line.Substring(1);
            return line;
        }
        else
        {
            return line;
        }
```

and this is the length method:

```
  private int length()
    {
 using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Path)){
            int count = 0;
   while(read.ReadLine() != null)
   {

       count++;
   }

   return count;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should also include your definitions of `length()` and `CheckLine`

Comment: If it is an array out of bound exception it is that you are seeking an index in the array which is over the size of the array. So pull your debugger and when you do the line[0] check what is in the line variable. In that case line is a string so consider it as an array of char.

Comment: the line variable there doesn't make sense.... it is "" I can also see that it is not the last element in the array. and the file it is reading from doesn't have that there.

Comment: Could the problem somehow be the data? I just hardcoded the one line it was stuck one and it did another hundred before getting stuck again. (was on #124 and went to #194)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. since 
   'lines[i] = null;' 
   in the next iteration of your loop if your following code is executed: 
   'lines[i - 1] = lines[i - 1] + line;'
   you will likely get a null reference exception (NRE) - pulling a string from null + someString. Instead you may 'lines[i] = "" // or String.empty'
2. Additionally since you wrote 'line.Substring(1);' you assume that there is a char in position 1 (second position since 1=0+1) and this may result in NRE if your sting has only one char. Check length of array before referring to the second (1) position- it may not exist, therefore will equal null.
3. Additionally I did not get into details but your wrote 'IsEnglishLetter(c[0])' and what happens it the string is "" or String.empty // does it have any chars (string.length==0)? Shall we get a second NRE?
   Hope this helps,
   P.Sz.
4. If your are a former COM or unmanaged programmer please note that assigning nulls to variables at the end of scope is not necessary to release the memory - if the object falls out of scope at some time it will be garbage collected, the GC makes a graph of the objects that are still used (those that have fallen out of scope are not referenced on the graph and will be garbage collected / will free memory at a time - automatically, without the need to assign them nulls)

Comment: okay! thanks! this has helped!, though I went back and fixed the data and that helped a lot too!